# How do you download a previous version of the iPhone SDK?

Tags: ios, iphone

I'm developing on the current 3.1 SDK, but I'd like my app to support all versions of the iPhone 2.2.1 onwards. I don't have a copy of the older SDKs around anymore and I can't find them on Apple's site. Is there still a way to get it from the iPhone Dev Center?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer you're looking for is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441321/how-to-get-iphone-sdk-2-2-1-for-xcode-3-2/1441440#1441440). Basically the SDK you want is part of the 3.1 SDK, you just have to configure your project to leverage it.